# Is it possible to use a custom Machine Learning model deployed on Google Cloud Platform in a Firebase application?

Tags: firebase, machine-learning, google-cloud-platform

I'm a beginner at Machine Learning and I have deployed a Collaborative Recommendation Model on Google Cloud Platform. I want to use the predictions from the model in a Firebase application. I would like to know if it's possible and how can I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use your model for predictions in multiple different ways. Since you have already deployed the model to GCP, an option would be to send [online prediction](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/online-predict) requests from your Firebase app using its [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/predict).

Another possibility is to use Firebase's ML Kit to use a [custom model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/use-custom-models). This allows you to either host your model in Firebase or include it directly into your app. You may need to transform your model into a [TensorFlow Lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/get_started) model first in order to use ML Kit. Please take into account that Firebase's ML Kit is still in a beta stage and its features may be subject to change.